# Return PDF file to user after ajax call to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have a custom button on my Kendo Grid "Export to PDF". On click of this button, I call a service which generates a PDF file.I want to be able to display this PDF file on click of the "Export to PDF" button. I have it working to the point where it calls the service and I save the PDF locally on my machine as of now. How can I return this file to the View so that its either displayed on a new tab or maybe just a dialog which asks the user to open and save the save.
The following is the button click method which make the call to the controller:

```
<script>
    function ExportDocGen_Click() {
        var grid = $("#companyMasterRateSheets").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        var orderQuoteId = selectedItem.QuoteID;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GenerateRateSheetPDF", "AccountDetail")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'string',
            cache: false,
            data: { 'orderQuoteId': orderQuoteId },
            success: function (color) {
                return color;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error occured');
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

The controller is as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
        public string GenerateRateSheetPDF(string orderQuoteId)
        {
byte[] pdfData = ServiceManager.BuildPDF(Convert.ToInt32(orderQuoteId));
            if (pdfData != null)
            {                   
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                bf.Serialize(ms, pdfData);                    
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("hello.pdf", pdfData);
            }          
            return ("hi");
}
```

I am returning string as of now since I am not sure what should the return type will be. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Because theres no people answer/comment this question yet. I think i need to give you help to do this thing generally (all language)

> I dont know about `.net` and `kendo` but i will give you live demo and simple explaination. My code written in PHP but i will try to explain this generally, because this is the common question for any web developer

There is two way to doing this:

1. Save file to storage then give user the produced link

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/generatePDF',
  success: function(d){
    document.location = d;
  }
})
```

**controller** (server side)

```
var pdf = createPDF();
saveToServer(pdf, 'path/filename.pdf');
```

this will give user pdf real path. (i think you dont want this in your case)

2. create file on the fly

**Html**

```
<a href="url_controller">description</a>
```

**controller** (server side)

```
var pdf = createPDF();
addHeader('Content-Disposition: attachment or inline');
printToScreen(pdf);
```

**pdf choice:**

- replace active tab
- open new tab
- open new window
- embed
- force download (client storage)
- save locally (server storage)

### 1. Replace Active Tab

- Basic HTML: `<a href="url">description</a>`
- Javascript /jquery `window.open(url, '_self');` 2nd param must be `_self` or `_parent`
- Requirement: Content-Disposition is not attachment

### 2. Open New Tab

- Basic HTML: `<a href="url" target="_blank">description</a>` depend on user preference setting
- Javascript /jquery `window.open(url, '_blank');` without 3rd parameter
- Requirement: Content-Disposition is not attachment

### 3. Open New Window

- Basic HTML: `<a href="url" target="_blank">description</a>` depend on user preference setting
- Javascript /jquery `window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=200');` with 3rd parameter
- Requirement: Content-Disposition is not attachment

### 4. Embed

- Basic HTML: `<embed src="url"></embed>`
- javascript/jquery: `$(selector).html('<embed src="url"></embed>');`
- Requirement: no matter Content-Disposition is attachment or not, browser always try to display it

### 5. Force Download (client storage)

- Basic HTML: `
- Javascript /jquery: `document.location = url;`
- Requirement: Content-Disposition is must be attachment

### 6. Save locally (server storage)

I will not explain this because:
 - you already doing this
 - And every language have different syntax

---

## Example Implementation

**index.html** (html + js)

```
<!-- 
    basic html: depend on user browser preference setting to open as new window or new tab
-->
<a href="http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/createpdf.php?file=dummy.pdf" target="_blank"><button id="newtab1">new tab/new window: basic html</button></a> 

<!--
    force to open new tab
    case: without ajax
-->
<button id="newtab2">new tab: jquery without ajax</button> 

<!--
    force to open new tab
    case: with ajax

    hint:
    * window.open() outside ajax will NOT BLOCKED
    * window.open() inside ajax will BLOCKED
    * so we need to hack this
    * 1st: prepare/declare new var to store blank window
    * 2nd: change location.href to execute it inside ajax
-->
<button id="newtab3">new tab: jquery with ajax</button> 

<!--
    force to open new window
    case: without ajax
-->
<button id="newwindow1">new window: jquery without ajax</button> 

<!--
    force to open new window
    case: with ajax
-->
<button id="newwindow2">new window: jquery with ajax</button> 

<!-- 
    embed
-->
<button id="embed">embed</button> 

<!--
    the most easy way
    force download using HTML5 anchor download attribute
    maybe not work for old browser
    hint:
    - no download attribute: display pdf
    - download attribute exists,  but content-disposition header is not set as attachment: display pdf
    - download attribute exists,  but content-disposition header is set as attachment: download pdf
-->
<a href="http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/createpdf.php?file=dummy.pdf" download="newname.pdf"><button id="forcedownload1">force download using anchor download attribute (fail)</button></a>  
<a href="http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/createpdf.php?file=dummy.pdf&force=1" download="newname.pdf"><button id="forcedownload1">force download using anchor download attribute (correct)</button></a>  

<!--
    force download using ajax
    i think this work in old browser too, since jquery take care of them
-->
<button id="forcedownload2">force download 2 using ajax/jquery</button> 

<hr>
<div id="preview-embed"></div>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){

    /*
    * you need to read window.open() first: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp to understand the basic
    * hint:
    * window.open() recieve 4 parameter
    * if we not set 3rd parameter: will force open new tab
    * if we set 3rd parameter: will force open new window
    */

    $('#newtab2').click(function(){
        /*
        * no matter content-disposition is attachment or not, it always display in browser
        */
        window.open('http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/createpdf.php?filename=dummy.pdf');
    });

    $('#newtab3').click(function(){
        var newWindow = window.open("","window name");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/givemethelink.php',
            success: function(d){
                newWindow.location.href = d;
            },
            error: function(d){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });

    $('#newwindow1').click(function(){
        window.open('http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/createpdf.php?filename=dummy.pdf','window name', 'width=200,height=100');
    });

    $('#newwindow2').click(function(){
        var newWindow = window.open("","window name", 'width=200,height=100');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/givemethelink.php',
            success: function(d){
                newWindow.location.href = d;
            },
            error: function(d){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });

    $('#embed').click(function(){
        $('#preview-embed').html('<embed src="http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/createpdf.php?file=dummy.pdf"></embed>');
    });

    $('#forcedownload2').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            /*
            * we need to get file with header attachment
            * if our file is dont have Content-Disposition: attachment , this ajax will display pdf only
            * so we need to set request parameter `force=1` 
            */
            url: 'http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/givemethelink.php?force=1', //correct
            //url: 'http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/givemethelink.php', //fail
            success: function(d){
                document.location = d;
            },
            error: function(d){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });


});
</script>
```

server scripting

server script example is written in PHP, please find the match syntax using your own language.

here i will implement method 2 only. i have so much different case. But i will choose the case which we have 2 script: 1. for give the link 2. generate pdf

**givemethelink.php** (only give url path)

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['force']) && $_GET['force'] ==1){ //if request GET parameter force exist and the value is 1
    echo 'http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/createpdf.php?filename=dummy.pdf&force=1';
}else{
    echo 'http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/createpdf.php?filename=dummy.pdf';
}
```

**createpdf.php** (generate pdf on the fly /method 2)

```
<?php
/*
* generate pdf on the fly here
* but here, i only use file_get_contents() to download existing pdf binary
* and then simply display it to the screen using echo
* because it can difficult to you to understand, if i give you real php generate pdf script
*/

$source = file_get_contents('dummy.pdf'); //download existing pdf. this line should be pdf generate script

/*
* set header. this is the key
* the main header requirement is Content-Disposition
* you still can set any other header which is optional
*/

header("Content-type: application/pdf"); //tell browser: this is pdf file (optional header example)

/*
* if is request GET force exists and the value is 1 : force download
* else display to the browser
*/

if(isset($_GET['force']) && $_GET['force'] ==1){
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=newname.pdf"); //tell browser: download this
}else{
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=newname.pdf"); //tell browser: display this file in browser
}

echo $source; //print pdf source to screen
```

`force=1` => give attachment header

`else` => give inline header

Here the live demo: http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/index.html

Conclusion:

1. Create script which genereate pdf on the fly not the real/direct pdf path
2. set header content-disposition: attachment or not, each have the different behaviour

bonus example: try run this code

**test.html**

```
<a href="http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/createpdf.php?filename=dummy.pdf">display 1</a> 
<a href="http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/createpdf.php?filename=dummy.pdf&force=1">download 1</a> 
<hr>
<a href="http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/createpdf.php?filename=dummy.pdf" target="_blank">display 2</a> 
<a href="http://creativecoder.xyz/stackoverflow/pdf-choice/createpdf.php?filename=dummy.pdf&force=1" target="_blank">download 2</a>
```